# How to update favicon to swirling load item when page is rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs application where I am attempting to change the favicon to a swirling icon whenever the page is rendering. I actually don't have the code for this and not sure where to start.

My aim is to have the favicon in the browser tab change to a swirling loading icon upon render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1 - [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)

You can define tags in the document's head during render, including the favicon.

```
const App = () => (
    <Helmet>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="you-swirling-icon.png">
    </Helmet>
)
```

#### Option 2 - Change the href attribute with a side effect

Here it's done using a hook, if you use a class component you can do the same in `componentDidMount`

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const favicon = document.getElementById('my-favicon')
        favicon = setAttribute('href', 'you-swirling-icon.png')
    }, [])

    return <div>Whatever is in your app</div>
}
```